# Set image in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have set image in **Actionbar** using

`ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header));`

and also removed `"android:icon="@drawable/header"` from `manifest.xml`

but I am getting one image overlapped over other. I am attaching snapshot.

[image]

I want to display only my image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

add this in your code you will get the desired output!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
```