# How to set Icon in Action bar menu item?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-volley, picasso

Below is my HomeActivity.java code. I have added two menu on action bar. What i want that i want to set user profile in actionProfile item. I have search a lot on google but could not found any solution related to my problem. I am getting user profile url through my web service using volley and I want to set user image in action bar menu. How can I achieve this ?

home_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionProfile"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile"
        android:title="Edit Profile">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionLogout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        android:title="Logout"/>
</menu>
```

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.actionProfile);
        if (item != null) {
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.profile);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.actionProfile:
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.actionLogout:
                logoutUser();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried searching in SO yet?  check this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911910/set-image-in-action-bar`

Comment: I want to set icon in perticular item from my home_menu.xml file. I am recieving image url from my webservice.

Comment: Have you tried using `.setIcon` and set the drawable that you receive from image url

Comment: I have used this "                        Picasso.with(ProfileActivity.this).load(AppConfig.profilePic + image).placeholder(R.drawable.edit_profile).transform(new CircleTransform()).fit().into(user_profile_photo);
" in my profile activity for display user profile image. but i am not getting how can i set image in R.id.actionProfile or how can I access this id to set image?

Comment: Can you post the whole code above?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19882555/7012517